# django ignoring admin.py

Tags: django, admin

I am trying to enable the admin for my app. I managed to get the admin running, but I can't seem to make my models appear on the admin page.
I tried following the tutorial ([here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin)) which says:

(Quote)

> Just one thing to do: We need to tell
>   the admin that Poll objects have an
>   admin interface. To do this, create a
>   file called admin.py in your polls
>   directory, and edit it to look like
>   this:

```
from polls.models import Poll from
django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Poll)
```

(end quote)

I added an `admin.py` file as instructed, and also added the following lines into `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

but it appears to have no effect. I even added a `print 1` at the first line of `admin.py` and I see that the printout never happens, So I guess django doesn't know about my `admin.py`. As said, I can enter the admin site, I just don't see anything other than "groups", "users" and "sites".
What step am I missing?

Comment: Do you have django admin listed in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @Silver Light - yes, I do. As said, I *can* enter the admin site. I just don't see anything other than "groups", "users" and "sites.

Comment: Second question: do you have app containing Poll listed in INSTALLED_APPS? :)

Comment: @Silver Light - thanks! that was it. If you post your answer I'll accept it, of course :)

Comment: Lol, i was having the same issue as you, but my admin.py file was so big, i didnt noticed I forgot to include the "admin.site.register(Poll)" thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to ensure you have app containing Poll listed in INSTALLED_APPS :)

Answer (score 1):

Also: If you're adding the admin.py file with the dev server running, make sure to restart it. This tripped me up for a minute. :)