# no Polls in admin page [django Tutorial 2]

Tags: django, django-admin

As I was following the [django tutorial part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/),
I got stuck because there is no *Polls* entry in the admin page.

- I have checked out the solution to this problem. They say that the poll app must be included in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. It is included.
- I have also restarted the server.
- I verified that I have done everything mentioned in the tutorial - everything worked up to now.
- The `admin.py` file from the polls directory seems to be ignored.

I have absolutely no idea what's wrong.

I run python 2.7.3 with django 1.4.2 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

**[SOLVED]**
This is something very strange.
As I was viewing my `admin.py` file with gedit, I have noticed that the key words, like `from` and `import` were not grey coloured, as they were in other `.py` files.
So I have copied and pasted the `models.py` file in the same folder, renamed it `admin.py`, deleted the old one and replaced the code with the original one. Now the key words were colored. And, yes, it worked perfectly!
So it must have been the way I created that `admin.py` file in ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

It is a little bit embarrassing, but it took me a while to solve this, since it wasn't a programming problem, as I expected, but an OS one.

Comment: didnt they rewrite the tutorial to use python 3?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: there's no error. Only if I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/polls/, I get the 404.

Comment: Interesting.  I will look at this later tonight since I don't have Django handy.

Comment: So, you think that the python version is the problem? I should try with python 3, then.

Comment: As I recall when I picked Django up a year or so ago after 4 years away, the tutorial had me use Python 3.  Of course this may just be my mistaken memory.

Comment: You are mistaken. The upcoming Django 1.5 is sort-of compatible with Python 3. Django 1.4 is not at all.

Comment: The only thing they say about the python version is "It requires Python version 2.5 or higher, but it has no dependencies on other Python libraries." https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Comment: My admin page looks just as if there were no admin.py file in the polls folder.

Comment: please post your `admin.py` file here

Comment: `from polls.models import Poll`
`from django.contrib import admin`
`admin.site.register(Poll)`

Comment: I have the same problem with [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546073/django-ignoring-admin-py), except his solution isn't working for me, since I have already done that.